# Conditionally set HTML element id with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, haml

I am attempting to write this html in haml so as to add an id tag if the item is the current one.  This is to setup for jquery highlighting.

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
<tr class="line_item id="current_item">
<% else %>
<tr class="line_item">
<% end %> 
  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td> 
  <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
```

Because I don't want to write a helper method, I've stuck the if statement within the tag:

```
%tr.line_item{ :id => (line_item == @current_item ? '' : 'current_item') }
%td
    = line_item.quantity
%td 
    \x #{line_item.product.title}
%td.item_price
    = number_to_currency(line_item.total_price)
%td.item_remove
    = button_to 'Remove', line_item, :method => :delete
```

However, this id tag of 'current_item' sticks with all the items and not just the current one.  This results in javascript highlighting all or the wrong entry.  Thoughts on how to get haml to cooperate?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ehm sir, your condition is wrong :-)

It should be

```
line_item == @current_item ? "current_item" : ""
```

There is a thing that's not pretty - you end up with `id=""` for rest of the items. But there is a simple cure for it:

```
%tr.lineitem{ :id => (line_item == @current_item ? "current_item" : nil)}
```

When you return `nil` value for an attribute HAML will ignore it and it will not appear in the output.

Comment: Thanks!  Wish I could make it cleaner

Comment: That's the "" that made me feel bad! :-)

Comment: the ability to use nil to "ignore" an attribute in HAML is an excellent tip - thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You can do this: `@tr.lineitem{class: ("current_item" if line_item == @current_item)}`

Comment: Why do you have to explicitly return `nil` here with a ternary, rather than just doing `("current_item" if line_item == @current_item)`?

I thought `if` would return nil by default whenever it's condition isn't met.

Answer (score 6):

This also works as an alternative for the first solution in the accepted answer

```
= f.input_field :hello, disabled: (true unless SOME_CONDITION_HERE)
```

Comment: This is especially useful for boolean attributes (like disabled).

Answer (score 1):

Taking @vladCovaliov's answer in the context of the question:

```
%tr.line_item{ id: (@current_item unless @current_item != line_item) }
```